# Tascam DR-680 ratings??

Tags: field-recording, portable-recorder, tascam-dr-680, pre-amp

I'm in the process of getting rid of my zoom h4n primarily because of the noisy circuitry inside. I have found that most tascam stuff is extremely quiet. With the zoom I use an MP1 sound device preamp but there is no way to bypass the electronics obviously in the zoom. My question is whats the quality of the preamps in the tascam dr 680? Would I need an external still or what they be good enough for the job. Obviously there are 8 inputs so I wouldn't be able to use my one channel pre on all of them. Also if anyone has had bad experiences or would recommend another recorder with more than 2 inputs. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the DR-680 is hands down the best purchase in the market unless you value something in the Sound Devices units (with at least triple the price) or it's oversized for your needs.

https://pantherfile.uwm.edu/type/www/audio-art-tech-gallery/pages/Emil_DR680_SD702_QuadMic_Compare-present.html

[Has anyone got experience with the Tascam DR-680?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/4204/has-anyone-got-experience-with-the-tascam-dr-680)

Comment: Thanks man! I just found that thread ha wish I found it before I asked .